# How to generate code coverage file with Frank automation - Locally (Without Jenkins/Hudson)

Tags: ios, cucumber, code-coverage, ui-automation, frank

I've seen various articles describing how to run Frank automation on Jenkins/Hudson using headless app running method. But is there a possibility to run the Frank Automation locally and generate the coverage files (gcno, gcda?)

How to make the test App quit gracefully with Frank and get the gcno and gcda ?